# Fastest way to find how many intervals are intersected by a given interval

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a list **L** of intervals **(l, r)**.

Picking one interval **i** from **L**, how can I know how many intervals **i** intersects with?

There is an extra constraint: the intervals from L can move (that is, if an interval is **(l, r)**, it can go to **(l+x, r+x)**).

What is the most performant way to perform this task?

---

My first thought was to do some sort of sweep-line algorithm, by sorting **L**, but I'm struggling at how I'm gonna sort it.

If I sort it by where each interval ends, I'll know how far I can go to the left index of **i** but not to the right. How should I sort it? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: fwiw, the stock solutions are [range trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree), [segment trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree), and [interval trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I'm assuming all this happens on a line, not in 2D/3D]

An interval does not intersect a given one if it's either starts after the given interval finish or finishes before the given interval start.

You could put all starts and all finishes into two separate data structures which allow to find out how many numbers are less/more than a given one and allows additions/removals. You can use a regular red-black tree which allows `O(logn)` insertions/removals and add number of child nodes to be able to get number of smaller elements in `O(logn)`.

So when we need to find how many intervals are intersected by a given one, we take the whole number of all intervals and subtract the number of intervals starting after the given interval finish and the number of intervals finishing before the given interval finish. Looks like `O(logn)`.

When we need to move some interval, we just remove its start and its finish from the corresponding collections and add the updated values. Looks like `O(logn)` too.

Comment: @trincot, my bad, I forgot that it's not possible to find distance between iterators in std::map. I've edited to explain how it can be done. Though the solution became less easy to implement...

Answer (score 0):

I would stick the intervals into a Quadtree, where the interval from `l` to `r`  goes to the point `(l, r)`.

And now the set of intervals that intersect the given one are all above and to the left of the point `(r, l)`.  Which is a query that a quad tree is reasonably efficient at.

To move an interval you simply remove it from the quadtree, place it at its new location, and repeat the query.